# Passing a string array from powershell to C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to call a C# program from powershell and pass an array of parameters from powershell to the C# program.  The C# program takes a file path, date, and file extension and manipulates those files.

In the powershell script I have, I store all the strings inside an array of strings and pass that string using the `-argumentlist` switch in `start-process`.

Since these file paths are at my work I am going to make up some file paths for an example.
The name of this script is `ProductionImportCaller`

```
$ParametersToPass = "C:\my images,20130412,dat", "C:\my images\curiosity,20130412,bif"

Start-Process -FilePath C:\Users\ABetterProductionImport.exe 
-ArgumentList $ParametersToPass
```

The above does not have a new line in my script.  I just make it a newline on here so it is easier to read.

When I call `.\ProductionImportCaller` the array that is passed is:

```
c:\my
images,20130412,dat  

c:\my
images\curiosity,20130412,bif
```

which I do not want.

So here is my question:
How do I write my powershell script so these parameters will pass correctly?

I have tried

1. Replacing the double quotes with single quotes
2. Surrounding each parameter with double quotes and surrounding the file path with singe quotes

This works if I call:

```
start-process .\ABetterProductionImport.exe "C:\my images,20130412,dat"
```

EDIT: But if I call the same command from a script that I wrote this does not work.
So again, how do I write a powershell script to make this run correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.  If I call

```
.\ABetterProductionImport.exe $ParametersToPass
```

exactly with no start-process or anything it works.  Which is good.